# Is it possible to send logs directly to splunk cloud using JavaScript as Google Analytic does?

Tags: javascript, logging, splunk

I want to track some client side interactions using splunk. I want to know whether it is possible using JavaScript to send some information (logs) to splunk cloud directly ?

Google analytic does the same .

Comment: @Shakeel, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30131870/implementing-server-logs-with-splunk

Please try to look into this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We actually have a [Splunk SDK for JavaScript](https://github.com/splunk/splunk-sdk-javascript) that you can use, and some documentation on [dev.splunk.com](http://dev.splunk.com/javascript). You'll want to use `service.log()` which you can pass a string or JS object, see our [example here](https://github.com/splunk/splunk-sdk-javascript/blob/master/examples/node/helloworld/log.js).

Please let me know if you need further guidance

Comment: Using  Splunk SDK for JavaScript , Can I log my logs directly to splunk instead of using Universal forwarder ?? Google Analytic does the same.

Comment: Yes, you don't need to use a forwarder

Comment: However, you'll probably want some kind of abstraction layer so your code is not tightly coupled to Splunk.