# Implementing server logs with splunk

Tags: log4j, server-side, splunk

folks !

i'm trying to log server logs over my splunk cloud, can you please explain how to implement this, i have setted up splunk with universal forwarder  and my client side logs are working fine, but how to put server side logs, i have idea about log4j.properties file but what to write in it, and in other files to reflect server logs on splunk site as well.
If you could help in simple terms that would be helpful.

Thank You so Much. !!

Comment: @Shakeel would  you look into this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I totally understand your question. Anyways, I think our [Java Logging Libraries](http://dev.splunk.com/view/splunk-logging-java/SP-CAAAE2K) may be helpful for you - we support Log4j

Answer (score 0):

You can log server logs similarly how you logging client logs. Update the server log file path in inputs.log.